# Using sortable with 2 KnockoutJS trees

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, treeview, knockout-sortable

Is it possible to use knockout-sortable with knockout-ui trees so that it's possible to drag items from one tree to another?

I've been trying to adapt the example from [RP Niemeyer](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable), but I just can't get it to work.

I can drag items from both trees but it won't let me drop them. I added the connectWith property as a parameter to the sortable plugin but it's not working.

Here is what I have so far:

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $(".availableItemsContainer .node").sortable({ connectWith: ".groupedItemsContainer" });

    $(".groupedItemsContainer .node").sortable({ connectWith: ".availableItemsContainer" });
});

ko.bindingHandlers.flash = {
    init: function (element) {
        $(element).hide();
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value) {
            $(element).stop().hide().text(value).fadeIn(function () {
                clearTimeout($(element).data("timeout"));
                $(element).data("timeout", setTimeout(function () {
                    $(element).fadeOut();
                    valueAccessor()(null);
                }, 3000));
            });
        }
    },
    timeout: null
};

ko.bindingHandlers.droppable = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var dropHandler = valueAccessor() || {};

        $(element).droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                var item = ko.utils.domData.get(ui.draggable[0], "ko_dragItem");

                if (item) {
                    item = item.clone ? item.clone() : item;
                    dropHandler.call(this, item, event, ui);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};

var DGViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.tree1 = {
        id: 'groupedItems',
        remember: true,
        children: [
            {
                name: "Annabelle",
                id: '1',
                isOpen: true,
                children: [
                    { name: "Arnie", cssClass: 'page', id: '5', children: [] },
                    { name: "Anders", cssClass: 'page', id: '6', children: [] },
                    { name: "Apple", cssClass: 'page', id: '7', children: [] }
                ]
            },
            {
                name: "Bertie",
                id: '2',
                children: [
                    { name: "Boutros-Boutros", cssClass: 'page', id: '8', children: [] },
                    { name: "Brianna", cssClass: 'page', id: '9', children: [] },
                    { name: "Barbie", cssClass: 'page', id: '10', children: [] },
                    { name: "Bee-bop", id: '4', children: [] }
                ]
            },
            { name: "Charles", id: '3', children: [] }
        ],
        dragHolder: ko.observable(undefined),
        handlers: {
            addNode: function(parent, type, name, onSuccess) {
                nextId = nextId + 1;
                onSuccess({ id: nextId, parent: parent, name: name, cssClass: type });
            }
        },
        logTo: '#log1',
        defaults: {
            'folder': {
                name: 'New Folder',
                childType: 'page'
            },
            'page': {
                name: 'New Page',
                isDraggable: true,
                isDropTarget: false,
                canAddChildren: false
            }
        },
        contextMenu: {
            contextMenus:
            [
                {
                    name: 'foldercontext',
                    width: 190,
                    items: [
                        {
                            text: 'Delete',
                            run: function(dataItem) {
                                dataItem.deleteSelf();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Rename',
                            run: function(dataItem) {
                                dataItem.isRenaming(true);
                            }
                        },
                        { separator: true },
                        {
                            text: 'New',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    text: 'Page',
                                    iconCssClass: 'page',
                                    run: function(dataItem) {
                                        dataItem.addChild({ type: 'page' });
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    text: 'Folder',
                                    iconCssClass: 'folder',
                                    run: function(dataItem) {
                                        dataItem.addChild({ type: 'folder' });
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: 'pagecontext',
                    width: 190,
                    items: [
                        {
                            text: 'Delete',
                            run: function(dataItem) {
                                dataItem.deleteSelf();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Rename',
                            run: function(dataItem) {
                                dataItem.isRenaming(true);
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            build: function(event, dataItem) {
                dataItem.selectNode();
                var type = dataItem.type();
                if (type == 'folder') {
                    return { name: 'foldercontext' };
                } else {
                    return { name: 'pagecontext' };
                }
            }
        }
    };

    self.tree2 = {
        id: 'availableItems',
        remember: true,
        children: [
            { name: "Test1", id: '300', cssClass: 'page', children: [] },
            { name: "Test2", id: '301', cssClass: 'page', children: [] },
            { name: "Test3", id: '302', cssClass: 'page', children: [] },
            { name: "Test4", id: '303', cssClass: 'page', children: [] }
        ],
        dragHolder: ko.observable(undefined),
        handlers: {
            addNode: function(parent, type, name, onSuccess) {
                nextId = nextId + 1;
                onSuccess({ id: nextId, parent: parent, name: name, cssClass: type });
            }
        },
        logTo: '#log1',
        defaults: {
            'folder': {
                name: 'New Folder',
                childType: 'page'
            },
            'page': {
                name: 'New Page',
                isDraggable: true,
                isDropTarget: false,
                canAddChildren: false
            }
        },
        contextMenu: {
            contextMenus:
            [
                {
                    name: 'foldercontext',
                    width: 190,
                    items: [
                        {
                            text: 'Delete',
                            run: function(dataItem) {
                                dataItem.deleteSelf();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Rename',
                            run: function(dataItem) {
                                dataItem.isRenaming(true);
                            }
                        },
                        { separator: true },
                        {
                            text: 'New',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    text: 'Page',
                                    iconCssClass: 'page',
                                    run: function(dataItem) {
                                        dataItem.addChild({ type: 'page' });
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    text: 'Folder',
                                    iconCssClass: 'folder',
                                    run: function(dataItem) {
                                        dataItem.addChild({ type: 'folder' });
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: 'pagecontext',
                    width: 190,
                    items: [
                        {
                            text: 'Delete',
                            run: function(dataItem) {
                                dataItem.deleteSelf();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Rename',
                            run: function(dataItem) {
                                dataItem.isRenaming(true);
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            build: function(event, dataItem) {
                dataItem.selectNode();
                var type = dataItem.type();
                if (type == 'folder') {
                    return { name: 'foldercontext' };
                } else {
                    return { name: 'pagecontext' };
                }
            }
        }
    };
};

var vm = new DGViewModel();

var nextId = 20;
vm.treeViewModel1 = new ko.tree.viewModel(vm.tree1);
vm.treeViewModel2 = new ko.tree.viewModel(vm.tree2);

ko.bindingHandlers.sortable.beforeMove = vm.verifyAssignments;
ko.bindingHandlers.sortable.afterMove = vm.updateLastAction;

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="availableItemsTreeViewWrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="availableItemsContainer">
            <div data-bind="tree : treeViewModel2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="availableItemsContextMenuContainer">
            <div style="padding: 10px;">
                <a href="#" id="add" data-bind="click : function() { treeViewModel2.addNode(); }">Add</a>
                <a href="#" id="delete" data-bind="click : treeViewModel2.deleteNode">Delete</a>
                <a href="#" id="delete" data-bind="click : treeViewModel2.renameNode">Rename</a>
            </div>
            <div id="log2" class="logger">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mainWrapper">
    <div id="groupedItemsTreeViewWrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="groupedItemsContainer">
                <div data-bind="tree : treeViewModel1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="groupedItemsContextMenuContainer">
                <div style="padding: 10px;">
                    <a href="#" id="add" data-bind="click : function() { treeViewModel1.addNode(); }">Add</a>
                    <a href="#" id="delete" data-bind="click : treeViewModel1.deleteNode">Delete</a>
                    <a href="#" id="delete" data-bind="click : treeViewModel1.renameNode">Rename</a>
                </div>
                <div id="log1" class="logger">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've done this without using the solution you're doing.  What I did was keep all of the ui interactions the same, and then handled everything in the events.  So I had a sortable binding (ko.bindingHandlers.sortable) with the value accessor keeping my options.  In the sortable binding I would have something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sortable = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {    
        options = valueAccessor();
        $(element).sortable({
            connectWith: options.connectWith || {},
            items: options.items || {},
            update: options.update || {}
        });
    }
};
```

and then in update I handle adding it from one list to another.  So you drop it in to your list (at this point it's in the DOM only) and the update catches it (or stop, depending on what you need.  Update fires on the first list AND the second list, stop is only the second list.)  Here you remove it from the first list (either explicitly or using ko.contextFor on the dom node) and then splice it into the second list.  At this point you'll have to remove the item from the ui, and this is as simple as ui.item.remove().  If you're storing this information in a database (either way) you'll have to keep a sequence on it since they'll just return in the order they were created no matter what.

This way is a good way to just make it work with jquery ui, but it doesn't really integrate.  You let jquery ui do its thing, and then update the model based on the end result.

--

So in the html what you're going to want to do is use the binding I mentioned above.  To do this, you'll bind both of your lists like so:

```
<div id="list1" data-bind="sortable: { connectWith: '#list2', update: updateListFunction, items: '.myItems' }, foreach: list1.items">
    <div class="myItems"></div>
</div>
<div id="list2" data-bind="sortable: { connectWith: '#list1', update: updateListFunction, items: '.myItems' }, foreach: list2.items">
    <div class="myItems"></div>
</div>
```

and then `updateListFunction` would be something in your contextual view model that is like this:

```
self.updateListFuntion = function() {
    //makes sure it only updates on the list to which the sorting applied, since it fires twice
    if (this === ui.item.parent()[0]){    
         //do your updating here, using the method in the second paragraph 
         //ko.contextFor(ui.item) will give you the original item to get it out of the list and move it into the next
         //a lot of the stuff that's going to happen here is array math and is a whole 'nother can of worms!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Maggie.

I've been trying to implement what you described, but I don't really know where to start.

Could you elaborate a little more reagarding what I need to do please? I'm kinda new to query/jquery, so I'm not sure exactly what to do and where to do it precisely.

FYI, I changed this:

    $(".availableItemsContainer .node").sortable();

    $(".groupedItemsContainer .node").sortable();

I also added the code you posted.

Comment: let me edit with what the html might look like, and let me know if that helps or not!

Comment: Thanks Maggie! I'll try it out today and I'll let you know if I managed to get it to work or not. I really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: Finally got the chance to try it out. Is this supposed to work with 2 treeviews? I need to be able to drag and drop items between the 2 trees. I can't seem to bind the items correctly...

Comment: No, this doesn't take into account the tree but it should give you the basic scaffolding.  You'll have to see what the trees use to get them to bind, and then do the updating in the jquery ui functions.  It looks like the tree has `startDrag` and `endDrag`, I'd recommend checking those out to see what that gets you.  Sorry I can't help with the tree part!

Comment: OK thanks a lot! I should be able to figure it out eventually.